# In the quiz app, I want to add a Picture under each question

Tags: java, android

I want to add a picture under each question. I am using Android studio.

```
String questions[] = {
    "Which method can be defined only once in a program?",
    "Which of these is not a bitwise operator?",
    "Which keyword is used by method to refer to the object that invoked it?"};
String answers[] = {"main method","<=","this"};
String opt[] = {
    "finalize method","main method","static method","private method",
    "&","&=","|=","<=",
    "import","this","catch","abstract"};
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Where can the user read/see those questions?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) to achieve that. Follow the setup instructions, then just add and edit this line:

```
Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

imageView is your ImageView in your xml layout file.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your questions are output in `TextView`. in this case, you can get the text from `TextView` (`tv1.getText().toString`), and then compare the resulting value with each array element in the loop (`tv1.getText.toString.equals(questions[n])`), so you can set your own image for each text.